# Importance of Skorokhods Theorem

Tags: probability-theory

I was wondering, what is the significance of Skorokhod theorem? More generally why can't most of probability theory be developed only referencing Random Variables indirectly? (In other words, only using the probability law or distribution function and not using the measure-theory based definition of a random variable being a measurable function on some probability space).

Comment: The point of the theorem is that you can pick $X_n$ to be random variables whose law is $\mu_n$ and they also converge a.s. to a random variable whose law is $\mu$, not just in distribution. This roughly speaking means that you can sort out the *joint* law of *all* the $X_n$ in such a way that the $X_n$ will also converge a.s. in addition to in distribution. A similar result whose significance is perhaps more apparent: one can produce a stochastic process given its finite dimensional distributions (provided that they satisfy a compatibility condition).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, the extension theorem shows the existence. But still this seems like additional machinery then is actually needed.